# How do you write an equation for a parabola that has certain roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

The question is

> Write a quadratic equation for a parabola that opens downwards and has zeros at $x=4$ and $x = -5$.

I don't even know where to start, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $p(x) = (x-4)(x+5)$

Comment: Doug.Opens downward?

Comment: What do you mean by opens downwards?

Comment: Thank you guys, Doug and Mohammad both answered exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I would interpret opens downwards to mean that the vertex is at the top of the parabola, in which case you want an equation of the form $y = a(x - 4)(x + 5)$, where $a < 0$.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, did you mean to say $k\lt0$ instead of $k\gt0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the axis is strictly vertical or parallel to x-axis we have

$$ y= -A (x-4)(x+5) $$

whre $A$ is positive real... when a parabolic shape container spills water or looks downwards.

If  the axis is not vertical then parabola

$$ y= a x+b + \sqrt{c x +d} $$

has roots

$$(c-2 a b \pm \sqrt {-4 a b c+c^2+4 a^2 d})/(2 a^2)$$

that is bit more cumbersome to work back.